# A Lunatic's Sequences

Tags: number-sequence

My uncle Todd is a little off his rocker. He's getting on in years, and sometimes I find him outside at night scratching numbers in the dirt with a stick. Last night I found him sitting quietly in front of his latest sets of numbers, gazing off at the city skyline that never seemed to rest. There were obvious marks where some numbers had once been but had been rendered incomprehensible by the breeze rolling in from the river.

Most people just call him crazy, but I think there's a method to his scribbling. Can you uncover his pattern and fill in the missing numbers?

> 1, 2, 3, __, 5, __, __, 8, 9, 9, __, 11, __
>   __, 8, 8, 7, __, 4, 4, __, 1, 30, __, __, 29
>   1, __, __, 14, 18, 22, 27, __, 35, 39, __, 48, 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears to be a lunar calendar, the first two line up pretty well with the month and day of new moons for 2016, the third with full Julian week.

So, here we are:

> 1, 2, 3, **4**, 5, **6**, **7**, 8, 9, 9, **10**, 11, **12**
> **9**, 8, 8, 7, **6**, 4, 4, **2**, 1, 30, **30**, **29**, 29
> 1, **6**, **10**, 14, 18, 22, 27, **31**, 35, 39, **43**, 48, 52
> Courtesy: http://www.calendar-12.com/moon_phases/2016